# Type and method could not be resolved in openCV

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to learn about openCV using Eclipse on windows 10. I am currently trying to get an example code compiled simply by copying and pasting. However, for some reason, the symbols in the files remain unresolved, even though i have made the settings (in properties -> C/C++ builders) to include the path to the folders and eclipse is indicating that it can find such path.

I have been trying for the past few days to no avail. What should i do to fix this problem? I have also tried including mat.hpp (where the Mat class is defined), but it didn't work either.
[image]

Comment: Put code and errors as text not images, this will just make harder for other people to answer your question

Comment: My apologies, but i used an image because i wanted to show that Eclipse is indicating that it could find the header file

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because cv::Mat is neither in `imgcodecs.hpp` nor in `highgui.hpp`.

Except for some contrib stuff possibly, you should never include the specific headers for OpenCV, but instead just

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

Also, I recommend against `using namespace cv;`, `using namespace` shouldn't be used (globally, in a scope is ok) at all, and `cv` does have some names in common with `std`.

If you really want to omit the `cv::` for some symbols, do e.g. `using cv::Mat;`, and do it inside a scope, e.g. at the start of a function, not globally.

Comment: +1 just for the namespace part (i think it is really important)... also, if you have `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` you do not need to include most of the modules...

Comment: hi, I have already included the 2 header files as you said, but the symbol is still unresolved

Comment: Is it perhaps a linker error? With the headers I mentioned, the compiler should find the functions. If you don't link against the right OpenCV libraries, the linker might have an issue.

Comment: Although I dont think this is a linker error, i have tried putting in the linker setting to include opencv library and i have also added the directory as well, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i have managed to figure out the problem. It was because i included the wrong directories. Initially, i include the path "opencv/sources/modules/core/include", but it should have been "opencv/build/include" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I add some

If you use mikefile, please refer to this link v1 https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d16/tutorial_linux_eclipse.html

Eclipse Photon makes it easier to use cmake, but you may need to enable indexer as there may be warnings of errors

[Https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html)

[enable indexer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo32g.png)

Sometimes you need or other include

```
#include <opencv4 / opencv2 / opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4 / opencv2 / core.hpp>
#include <opencv4 / opencv2 / highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4 / opencv2 / imgcodecs.hpp>
```